# How do I click and press keys using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to find a Google Place ID of Statue of Liberty National Monument from a Google's developer website: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css

I want to click on the search bar where it says "[Enter a location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JLWT.jpg)", type "Statue of Liberty National Monument", press down arrow key, and press enter key to get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC1Q8.jpg).

However, my code doesn't even click the search bar. Please help me.

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
Google_IDS = ['https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css']

for Google_ID in Google_IDS:
  driver.get(Google_ID)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  
  Google_ID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/input')
  Google_ID.click()
  Google_ID.send_keys('Statue of Liberty National Monument')
  Google_ID.send_keys('keys.DOWN')
  Google_ID.send_keys('keys.ENTER')
```

Updated Code:

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
Google_IDS = ['https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css']

for Google_ID in Google_IDS:
  driver.get(Google_ID)
  wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.devsite-article-body.clearfix > div > devsite-iframe > iframe")))
  Google_ID = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pac-input')
  Google_ID.send_keys('Statue of Liberty National Monument')
  dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.pac-container.pac-logo > div')))
  dropdown.click()

  ID_Info = driver.find_element(By.ID, "place-id")
  print("Google ID:", ID_Info.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Use following code

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files(x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
Google_IDS = ['https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css']

for Google_ID in Google_IDS:
  driver.get(Google_ID)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  
  Google_ID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/input')
  Google_ID.click()
  Google_ID.send_keys('Statue of Liberty National Monument')
  Google_ID.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
  Google_ID.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

For more :https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-keyboard/

Comment: It doesn't click the search bar at all.

Comment: I think there is a problem with xpath locator , i will try to get another one

Comment: We will use CSS extend of xpath

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
Google_IDS = ['https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css']

for Google_ID in Google_IDS:
  driver.get(Google_ID)
  wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.devsite-article-body.clearfix > div > devsite-iframe > iframe")))
  Google_ID = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pac-input')
  Google_ID.send_keys('Statue of Liberty National Monument')
  dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.pac-container.pac-logo > div')))
  dropdown.click()
```

Your element is in an iframe and the way to send non strings such as keys are as follows. Also don't use a generic xpath as those are brittle and generally will break instead use a more inclusive selector.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The code typed "Statue of Liberty National Monument", but a down key and an enter key aren't working. I added "wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)" between entering the keys, yet it still did not work.

Comment: Seems like the dropdown was in another tag. The edit should select the first div in that list. Keys.ENTER and Keys.DOWN weren't working since it wasn't that element that had the values in it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I can't print out the place ID on python. I updated my post by adding two lines of code to print out the place ID. Could you please fix what I did wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure but it may be under some shadow roots from what I can see from that page.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution with using Exmplity wait and also you don't need to press down key may just Enter key

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files(x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
Google_IDS = ['https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder#maps_places_placeid_finder-css']

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
for Google_ID in Google_IDS:
  driver.get(Google_ID)
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.devsite-article-body.clearfix > div > devsite-iframe > iframe"))
  
  Google_ID = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.devsite-article-body.clearfix > div > devsite-iframe > iframe")
  Google_ID.click()
  Google_ID.send_keys('Statue of Liberty National Monument')
  Google_ID.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```